# Apache Rewrite Exclusion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble figuring out how to exclude /public/bin from this rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !firerift.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ firerift.php/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !firerift.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/bin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ firerift.php/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I finally found a well written reference for all things .htaccess http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/